# Add hyperlink to new image after onclick image change

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to add a hyperlink to an image after an onclick function was used to change the image. The onclick image change works but having a hard time with adding a link to the changed image.

```
<div class="masonary16 ms mblogvid"><img id="ms16" src="Images/img1.jpg" 
height="100%" onclick="overimg(); imglink();"/></div>



function overimg() {
document.getElementById("ms16").src = "Images/OVER/img2.jpg"; 
}

function imglink() {    
var parentEl = document.getElementById("ms16").parent;
var imgEl = parentEl.innerHtml;
parentEl.innerHtml = '<a href="http://www.google.com">' + imgEl + '</a>';}
```

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: What are you trying to do with 'imglink' function?

Comment: Trying to add a link to the new image.

Comment: You mean a hyperlink?

Comment: Sorry,  yes a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an element `<a>`,set its link(url),wrap the image inside it using `appendChild()` method and then wrap this inside the `div`.

```
<div class="masonary16 ms mblogvid">
    <img id="ms16" src="Images/scoge-menswear-16.jpg" height="100%" onclick="overimg(); imglink(this);"/>
</div> 



function imglink(img) { 
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href','url');
    var parentEl = document.getElementById("ms16").parentElement; 
    link.appendChild(img);
    parentEl.appendChild(link);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try parent div as href. then I think you can solve the problem. here is my option

```
<a href="" class="masonary16 ms mblogvid">
 <img id="ms16" src="Images/scoge-menswear-16.jpg" height="100%"onclick="overimg(); imglink();"/>
</a>

function imglink() {    
    var parentEl = document.getElementById("ms16").parent;
    parentEl.href="xyz.php"; 
   return false;;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is `parentElement` not `parent` ,but this function can only display html I think.So not working with `.innerHTML`. But we can get class names by classList ,so take one class and grab html could be work ...

```
function imglink() {
var parentEl = document.getElementById("ms16").parentElement;
var imgEl = document.getElementsByClassName(parentEl.classList[0]);
imgEl[0].innerHTML = '<a href="http://www.google.com">'+imgEl[0].innerHTML+'</a>';
}
```